# Type checking on multiple function's arguments in an array or rest parameter

Tags: typescript

I need to store multiple different functions that have a single parameter alongside the argument for that parameter.

I've been able to get it to work and have type checking for one type of function at a time but I want to be able to pass in multiple different types of functions at a time and get the correct type checking for the argument of that function.

```
type WalkOptions = {
    x: number
    speed: number
}

type JumpOptions = {
    y: number
    speed: number
}

type ShootOptions = {
    type: string
    duration: number
}

const walk = (options: WalkOptions)=>{}
const jump = (options: JumpOptions)=>{}
const shoot = (options: ShootOptions)=>{}

type Action<T extends (options: any) => void> = {
    command: T
    args: Parameters<T>[0]
}

function add<T extends (options: any) => void>(...actions: Action<T>[]){}
```

Using the above code I can do `add({command: walk, args:{x: 10, speed: 1}})` and I'll get the correct type checking on args. I can also do `add({command: walk, args:{x: 10, speed: 1}}, {command: walk, args:{x: -10, speed: 2}})` and everything works fine.

However if I do `add({command: walk, args:{x: 10, speed: 1}}, {command: jump, args:{x: 5, speed: 1}})` I'll get a type error on `command: jump` as it's expecting `(options: WalkOptions) => void`.

Is there anything I can do so that I can use add like this and still get type checking on args for the command that it's being used with.

```
add({
    command: walk,
    args:{
        x: 10,
        speed: 1
    }
},
{
    command: jump,
    args:{
        y: 5,
        speed: 1
    }
},
{
    command: shoot,
    args:{
        type: "laser",
        duration: 3
    }
},
{
    command: walk,
    args:{
        x: -10,
        speed: 2
    }
})
```

Also would it be possible to create an array of these Actions with type checking to be used on add like `add(...actionArray)`

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wOKryw) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't want to infer a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) for the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type argument for `T`, which is actually good in your case, since `Action<T>` for a union will end up mixing parameters together. You don't want `walk` to accept `JumpOptions` and vice versa.

Instead of having your function generic in the `Action` type argument for each *element type*, you can have it generic in the [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) of these type arguments.  And then you can use a [mapped tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) to convert that into the type of `actions`:

```
function add<T extends ((options: any) => void)[]>(
  ...actions: { [I in keyof T]: Action<T[I]> }
) { }
```

So instead of `T` being `A | B | C` and then having `actions` be of type `Action<A | B | C>`, you have `T` as `[A, B, C]` and then `actions` is of type `[Action<A>, Action<B>, Action<C>]`.

Let's test it:

```
add(
  { command: walk, args: { x: 10, speed: 1 } },
  { command: jump, args: { y: 5, speed: 1 } },
  { command: shoot, args: { type: "laser", duration: 3 } },
  { command: walk, args: { x: -10, speed: 2 } }
); // okay
/* T inferred as [
  (options: WalkOptions) => void, 
  (options: JumpOptions) => void, 
  (options: ShootOptions) => void, 
  (options: WalkOptions) => void
]> */
```

Looks good.  And if you make a mistake, it will be caught:

```
add(
  { command: walk, args: { x: 10, speed: 1 } },
  { command: shoot, args: { y: 5, speed: 1 } }, // error!
  // ---------------------> ~  
  // Object literal may only specify known properties, 
  // and 'y' does not exist in type 'ShootOptions'.
  { command: shoot, args: { type: "laser", duration: 3 } },
  { command: walk, args: { x: -10, speed: 2 } }
);
/* T inferred as [
  (options: WalkOptions) => void,
  (options: ShootOptions) => void, 
  (options: ShootOptions) => void, 
  (options: WalkOptions) => void
] */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/pt/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA6ghgGwNYHkzAJYHsB2BnKAXigG8AoKKADwC4ocBXAWwCMIAnCqPSCAEzqNWHMgF8yZUJCgApZmDSZcBYuUohBzNp0o8I-TcM7jJ4aAGUAFlizBF2fEVJcpEOnmDsMOAOZc+DOxwSjiG2mISAMbKwFAA7ohITgAUWOgOeHTwyPbKAJREAHykUOLR+LEAVvIpaSGZsvK5+AWExSSlZOUe3Na2tenKdFY2doMtRSUmrlAAgpEhADwAKlAQVMAQOHwEqeMNcDggrcUAblgYfMWqXNFMTIcCUMtccOw+DQAKb3BMEJvsPArQoAbQADABdCJkABmDBwCwcUDgfD4KzWGy2OygyT29Toh2Ok3OlzyIIhhWSXAAdLS4IihiUQQBJKDeKBICAgLAw54QujzJbLFkUzoFDomMgovhUygdO4PbZ0BLIAA0yPeDQ6tCgAEYweq9AY9aVSqquPKsPdHnRqkwwOq3h86B0NFAAKyG3hPXWm0TmuVQBU23qjR2al1QVx0ABECDgeA4MfVASCIToAGY-QGSsGlfFEuHnSUdQBafVe-RPABMfrIeQA3FAAPTNqBYJBwEBkZsAKmebJwMI47H4yIIIK4eIyWUSzTwJygJL46qndRnjXt88Xy9XlGnjJGtm3xIuK6ga-2s5y+x3Z7Iot7zYk0tluatiqeKqQRa11DoFbcN6AHZhaQYfiGeB9MAv6Rm6npAVWIGiGaLZtiOWDsAAhFwrZQKWBGEURxEkcUAB+lC4W2KAsJUEALFACAYACiBQA8IDtjgCAcXokQYDCHFIDgWBxDgUBgOwaQcJgEB4HuaHItsUAAOQgMpUB8Fgsn0P06wYD07IzMpR5jPUynUmBeZPFBYYasWHTRlAcYJkmKaBMEDiZqBgZWcqhZ2X+ZaAUaNZ1o2Pb9qs3jDuwo58OOUCTvu66MtkqC3qelw5ge+DDNBJ5tEuZ7yTlDQmQVZzFReyVXrAc4ZYVy4PlAT4SEAA)